# How to use inout and reg together in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have the following code:

```
module s(clock, direction, readWrite, LA1, LA2, LA3, LA4, LD1, LD2, LD3, LD4, RA1, RA2, RA3, RA4, RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4);
// parameters
input clock, direction, readWrite;      
inout reg [7:0] LD1, LD2, LD3, LD4, RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4;
inout reg [11:0] LA1, LA2, LA3, LA4, RA1, RA2, RA3, RA4;

// code
always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(direction==1) begin          // left to right
        assign RA1 = LA1 | LA2 | LA3 | LA4;
        assign RD1 = LD1 | LD2 | LD3 | LD4;     
        assign { RA2, RA3, RA4 } = RA1;
        assign { RD2, RD3, RD4 } = RD1;     
    end else begin
        if(direction==1) begin      // right to left
            assign LA1 = RA1 | RA2 | RA3 | RA4;
            assign LD1 = RD1 | RD2 | RD3 | RD4;     
            assign { LA2, LA3, LA4 } = LA1;
            assign { LD2, LD3, LD4 } = LD1; 
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

But, on the 2nd line, the "inout reg [7:0] LD1, ..." declaration throws a syntax error in VeritakWin 3.84F. (Veritak allows "output reg" together as I have a similar code after the given code in my program). If I remove the "reg", I get the error in the assign line. If I remove "inout", I obviously get an error. I even tried removing the "assign" keywords, and also by replacing "=" with "<=" , but still errors remain. What am I doing wrong? (I am new to Verilog)

Comment: Inout port is **bidirectional port**, means it's an **input port** with some part of your design but also the **output port** of some other part of your design, and you can't assign any value for the design output port, because their values are directly computed from the value of other input port. `inout` ports cannot be declared as `reg`, since they can be used as either input port (as wire) or output port (as reg or wire).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inout` ports can not be of type `reg`. The type of `assign` you have used to assign value to `inout` port is called **procedural continuous assignment** but this is not allowed for that kind of port. You must use **continuous assignment** instead. In your code:

```
module s(clock, direction, readWrite, LA1, LA2, LA3, LA4, LD1, LD2, LD3, LD4, RA1, RA2, RA3, RA4, RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4);
// parameters input clock, direction, readWrite;      
inout [7:0] LD1, LD2, LD3, LD4, RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4;
inout [11:0] LA1, LA2, LA3, LA4, RA1, RA2, RA3, RA4;

// left to right
assign RA1 = (direction) ? (LA1 | LA2 | LA3 | LA4) : 'bz;
assign RD1 = (direction) ? (LD1 | LD2 | LD3 | LD4) : 'bz;     
assign { RA2, RA3, RA4 } = (direction) ? RA1 : 'bz;
assign { RD2, RD3, RD4 } = (direction) ? RD1 : 'bz;     

// right to left
assign LA1 = (!direction) ? (RA1 | RA2 | RA3 | RA4) : 'bz;
assign LD1 = (!direction) ? (RD1 | RD2 | RD3 | RD4) : 'bz;     
assign { LA2, LA3, LA4 } = (!direction) ? LA1 : 'bz;
assign { LD2, LD3, LD4 } = (!direction) ? LD1 : 'bz; 

endmodule
```

Note that you can not read and write `inout` port at the same time, so high impedance value is set when reading.